# Classification Problems

Tags: soft-question, ct.category-theory, big-list, examples

I was thinking about the famous question in philosophy of mathematics: "When are two proofs the same?" and I was wondering if we could somehow "classify" proofs by establishing some sort of functorial relationship between proofs and other mathematical objects which we can classify (like for example, surfaces; my initial idea was to somehow capture the logical structure of a proof in a graph and then classify graphs by their topological structure). I searched MO and found [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3776/when-are-two-proofs-of-the-same-theorem-really-different-proofs) interesting post which contained some similar ideas.

However, I was wondering if we can come up with a list of examples of classification problems in mathematics which have been answered using category theoretic tools by functorially "translating" the original problem into a different category in which we can classify the corresponding objects... and everything works in a nice way. The natural place to start is obviously algebraic topology.

Comment: I think this is a too broad question. There are too many examples for this paradigm of translating classifications (lie groups -> lie algebras, complex manifolds -> complex varieties, field extensions -> groups, etc.), I don't know if such a big list will be an enrichment.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the first one on a number of people's minds is moduli spaces. More specifically, we can in Top form a moduli space (of curves, say), but not in the category of schemes. Thus stacks were born...